# C: How Efficient Are Output Routines in Terms of Buffering?

Tags: c, performance, file-io, io, buffer

I can't find any information on whether buffering is already implicitly done out of the box when one is writing a file with either `fprintf` or `fwrite`. I understand that this might be implementation/platform dependent feature. What I'm interested in, is whether I can at least expect it to be implemented efficiently on modern popular platforms such as Windows, Linux, or Mac OS X?

AFAIK, usually buffering for I/O routines is done on 2 levels:

1. Library level: this could be C standard library, or Java SDK (`BufferedOutputStream`), etc.;
2. OS level: modern platforms extensively cache/buffer I/O operations.

My question is about **#1**, not **#2** (as I know it's already true). In other words, can I expect C standard library implementations for all modern platforms to take advantage of buffering?

If not, then is manually creating a buffer (with cleverly chosen size) and flushing it on overflow a good solution to the problem?

### Conclusion

---

Thanks to everyone who pointed out functions like `setbuf` and `setvbuf`. These are the exact evidence that I was looking for to answer my question. Useful extract:

> All files are opened with a default allocated buffer (*fully buffered*)
>   if they are known to not refer to an interactive device. This function
>   can be used to either set a specific memory block to be used as buffer
>   or to disable buffering for the stream.
>
> The default streams `stdin` and `stdout` are fully buffered by default if
>   they are known to not refer to an interactive device. Otherwise, they
>   may either be *line buffered* or *unbuffered* by default, depending on the
>   system and library implementation. The same is true for `stderr`, which
>   is always either line buffered or unbuffered by default.

Comment: Realistically, what do the think the chances are that world has suffered gross inefficiency in something so basic all these years?  Set `setbuf` etc., as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases buffering for stdio routines is tuned to be consistent with typical block size of the operating system in question. This is done to optimize the number of I/O operations in the default case. Of course you can always change it with `setbuf()/setvbuf()` routines.

Unless you are doing something special, you should stick to the default buffering as you can be quite sure it's mostly optimal on your OS (for the *typical* scenario).

The only case that justifies it is when you want to use stdio library to interact with I/O channels that are not geared towards it, in which case you might want to disable buffering altogether. But I don't get to see cases for this too often.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely assume that standard I/O is sensibly buffered on any modern system.

Comment: "Standard I/O" is a C library concept. The whole point of standard I/O in the C library  is to allow you to write sensible code without having to think about how the OS handles I/O.

Comment: I know that. The question was different: whether there is out-of-the-box support for buffering in C standard library implementations on modern platforms. In fact, what I was looking for was `setbuf`, which I didn't know about since I don't program in C that often.

Comment: @Haroogan I thought your use case was that you wanted to make sure you would get sensible buffering without having to worry about the specifics of each platform. If so, then you don't want `setbuf`, because that's only useful if you know the best way to buffer on each particular platform you're using. What you want is to know if modern platforms provide sensible defaults, so you don't have to call `setbuf` or otherwise muck with it. And the answer is, yes, they do, for precisely that reason -- so you don't have to muck with it and know about the right way to buffer on each platform.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. All I needed was just the evidence that C standard library does buffering by default, and I found it thanks to `setbuf`.

Comment: And that was precisely what my one sentence answer said!

Answer (score 1):

As @David said, you can expect sensible buffering (at both levels).

However, there can be a huge difference between `fprintf` and `fwrite`, because `fprintf` interprets a format string.
If you stack-sample it, you can find a significant percent of time converting doubles into character strings, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

The C IO library allows to control the way buffering is done (inside the application, before what the OS does) with `setvbuf`.  If you don't specify anything, the standard requires that "when opened, a stream is fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to
refer to an interactive device.", the requirement also holds for `stdin` and `stdout` while `stderr` is not buffered even if one could detect that it is directed to a non interactive device.